# Smart ctrl-backspace in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there any setting in Eclipse that would permit the following functionality?

On ctrl-backspace (Delete Word Backwards), if we are at the lower-upper case boundary in a variable name and we're deleting the first part, and the first part is all lower case, turn the first letter of the next part into lower case.

In other words, if we have

new||Price

then ctrl-backspace would result in

||price

rather than

||Price

as it stands by default.

Comment: I'll take a look but the java tag doesn't apply to this question... I don't think. Variable names aren't exclusive to java and you don't need the help of java coding experts in this case.

Comment: A search of the likely properties pages and help menu lead to nothing you're looking for. Sorry